# SharePoint 2010 Create Document Id when new document is added in document library

Tags: sharepoint

I am new with SharePoint document library system with 2010 foundation. I need to create a document Id (auto generated one) whenever I add a new document in my SharePoint library. Do I need to write an event receiver or anything else ?

Any reference or guidelines are appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: There is a Q&A site from Stack Exchange just for SharePoint. You can access it here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com =)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need neither event receiver nor any code. Every item of document library (and any list) automatically gets unique ID whenever item is created.